# How to iterate a variable in XPATH, extract a link and store it into a list for further iteration

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm following a Selenium tutorial for an Amazon price tracker (Clever Programming on Youtube) and I got stuck at getting the links from amazon using their techniques.

tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbJeL_Av2-Q&t=4315s

I realized the problem laid on the fact that I'm only getting one link out of the 17 available after doing the product search. I need to get all the links for every product after doing a search and them use then to get into each product and get their title, seller and price.

funtion get_products_links() should get all links and stores them into a list to be used by the function get_product_info()

```
    def get_products_links(self):
    self.driver.get(self.base_url) # Go to amazon.com using BASE_URL
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox')
    element.send_keys(self.search_term)
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2) # Wait to load page
    self.driver.get(f'{self.driver.current_url}{self.price_filter}')
    time.sleep(2) # Wait to load page
    result_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('s-result-list')

    links = []
    try:
        ### Tying to get a list for Xpath links attributes ###
        ### Only numbers from 3 to 17 work after doing product search where 'i' is placed in the XPATH ###
        i = 3
        results = result_list[0].find_elements_by_xpath(
            f'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/a')
        links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in results]
        return links
    except Exception as e:
        print("Didn't get any products...")
        print(e)
        return links
```

At this point get_products_links() only returns one link since I just made 'i' a fixed value of 3 to make it work for now.

I was thinking to iterate 'i' in some sort so I can save every different PATHs but I don't know how to implement this.

I've tried performing a for loop and append the result into a new list but them the app stops working

Here is the complete code:

```
from amazon_config import(
get_web_driver_options,
get_chrome_web_driver,
set_browser_as_incognito,
set_ignore_certificate_error,
NAME,
CURRENCY,
FILTERS,
BASE_URL,
DIRECTORY
)
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class GenerateReport:
    def __init__(self):
    pass
class AmazonAPI:
def __init__(self, search_term, filters, base_url, currency):
    self.base_url = base_url
    self.search_term = search_term
    options = get_web_driver_options()
    set_ignore_certificate_error(options)
    set_browser_as_incognito(options)
    self.driver = get_chrome_web_driver(options)
    self.currency = currency
    self.price_filter = f"&rh=p_36%3A{filters['min']}00-{filters['max']}00"
    
def run(self):
    print("Starting script...")
    print(f"Looking for {self.search_term} products...")
    links = self.get_products_links()
    time.sleep(1)
    if not links:
        print("Stopped script.")
        return
    print(f"Got {len(links)} links to products...")
    print("Getting info about products...")
    products = self.get_products_info(links)

    # self.driver.quit()

def get_products_info(self, links):
    asins = self.get_asins(links)
    product = []
    for asin in asins:
        product = self.get_single_product_info(asin)

def get_single_product_info(self, asin):
    print(f"Product ID: {asin} - getting data...")
    product_short_url = self.shorten_url(asin)
    self.driver.get(f'{product_short_url}?language=en_GB')
    time.sleep(2)
    title = self.get_title()
    seller = self.get_seller()
    price = self.get_price()

def get_title(self):
    try:
        return self.driver.find_element_by_id('productTitle')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(f"Can't get title of a product - {self.driver.current_url}")
        return None

def get_seller(self):
    try:
        return self.driver.find_element_by_id('bylineInfo')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(f"Can't get title of a product - {self.driver.current_url}")
        return None

def get_price(self):
    return '$99'

def shorten_url(self, asin):
    return self.base_url + 'dp/' + asin

def get_asins(self, links):
    return [self.get_asin(link) for link in links]

def get_asin(self, product_link):
    return product_link[product_link.find('/dp/') + 4:product_link.find('/ref')]
    
def get_products_links(self):
    self.driver.get(self.base_url) # Go to amazon.com using BASE_URL
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_id('twotabsearchtextbox')
    element.send_keys(self.search_term)
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2) # Wait to load page
    self.driver.get(f'{self.driver.current_url}{self.price_filter}')
    time.sleep(2) # Wait to load page
    result_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('s-result-list')

    links = []
    try:
        ### Tying to get a list for Xpath links attributes ###
        ### Only numbers from 3 to 17 work after doing product search where 'i' is placed ###
        i = 3
        results = result_list[0].find_elements_by_xpath(
            f'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/a')
            
        links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in results]
        return links
    except Exception as e:
        print("Didn't get any products...")
        print(e)
        return links


  if __name__ == '__main__':
print("HEY!!!")
amazon = AmazonAPI(NAME, FILTERS, BASE_URL, CURRENCY)
amazon.run()
```

Steps to Run the script:

Step 1:
install Selenium==3.141.0 into your virtual environment

Step 2:
Search for Chrome Drivers on google and download the driver that matches you Chrome version. After download, extract the driver and paste it into your working folder

Step 3:
create a file called amazon_config.py and insert the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

DIRECTORY = 'reports'
NAME = 'PS4'
CURRENCY = '$'
MIN_PRICE = '275'
MAX_PRICE = '650'
FILTERS = {
  'min': MIN_PRICE,
  'max': MAX_PRICE
}
BASE_URL = "https://www.amazon.com/"

def get_chrome_web_driver(options):
  return webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

def get_web_driver_options():
  return webdriver.ChromeOptions()

def set_ignore_certificate_error(options):
  options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

def set_browser_as_incognito(options):
  options.add_argument('--incognito')
```

If you performed the steps correctly you should be able to run the script and it will perform the following:

1. Go to [www.amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com)
2. Search for a product (In this case "PS4")
3. Get a link for the first product
4. Visit that product link

Terminal should print:

```
HEY!!!
Starting script...
Looking for PS4 products...
Got 1 links to products...
Getting info about products...
Product ID: B012CZ41ZA - getting data...
```

What I'm not able to do is to get all links and iterate them so the script will visit all links in the first page

If you are able to get all links, the terminal should print:

```
HEY!!!
Starting script...
Looking for PS4 products...
Got 1 links to products...
Getting info about products...
Product ID: B012CZ41ZA - getting data...
Product ID: XXXXXXXXXX - getting data...
Product ID: XXXXXXXXXX - getting data...
Product ID: XXXXXXXXXX - getting data...
 # and so on until all links are visited
```

Comment: So the code you posted works the way you expect it to?  And you didn't include the code that isn't working?

Comment: first you could add in question (not in comments) link to tutorial - and you could check how old is this tutorial. Pages change content and tools and old tutorials can be useless. Second: Amazon have big money for security system which maybe can detect bots/scripts - even if you use Selenium.

Comment: maybe first you use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. Maybe you need some `for`-loop to process all data - and without `for`-loop maybe you may process only one link from list.

Comment: I see `i = 3` but maybe you should put code in `for i in range(3, 18)` and `append()` `results` to list `links` (instead of creating new list `links`) and use `return` after this `for`-loop - or maybe even after exiting `try/except`

Comment: maybe you should use simpler `xpath` with `//` to skip some `divs` - especially `div[{i}]` - and then maybe it gets all needed elements at once.

Comment: @alexpdev Yes the code I posted works but only for one link. For the script to work properly it needs to get all links after a product search and thats where I got stock. I'll post the code for amazon.config and some instructions so everyone can run it

Comment: @furas The tutorial is only 1 year old and everything else works except getting links after a product search since amazon always changes their html to make it harder to scrape their info. I'll add the tutorial link at the end of the question so everyone can watch it and follow their steps. At this time I have ran the scripts hundred times with some time in between (1-3 minutes) and I had no issues with amazon.

Comment: 1 year is long time - they could change page few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run it so I only guess how I would do it.

I would put all `try/except in` for`-loop, and use links.append()` instead of `links = [...]`, and I would use `return` after exiting loop

```
    # --- before loop ---
    
    links = []
    
    # --- loop ---
    
    for i in range(3, 18):
        try:
            results = result_list[0].find_elements_by_xpath(
            f'//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[{i}]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/a')
            
            for link in results:
                links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
                
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Didn't get any products... (i = {i})")
            print(e)
        
    # --- after loop ---
    
    return links
```

---

But I would also try to use `xpath` with `//` to skip most of `divs` - and maybe if I would skip `div[{i}]` then I could get all products without `for`-loop.

---

**BTW:**

In `get_products_info()` I see similar problem - you create empty list `product = []` but later in loop you assing value to `product = ...` so you remove previous value from `product`. It would need `product.append()` to keep all values.

Something like

```
def get_products_info(self, links):

    # --- before loop ---
    asins = self.get_asins(links)
    product = []

    # --- loop ---
    for asin in asins:
        product.append( self.get_single_product_info(asin) )

    # --- after loop ---
    return product
```

Comment: This works perfectly!!!  Thanks a lot for you answer!!! if you want to try the script you can follow the steps that I included at the end of the question. Also, the function get_products_info() is not completed at this point in the tutorial. By now it only gets the product asin and prints it into the terminal but it does what is intended to do so far.